# PowerShell open Excel File - Error Name conflict

Tags: excel, powershell

i'm not able to open an excel file via PowerShell without getting an error "Name conflict" for "old Name = _FilerDatabase". If i tried to open via double click, i got no errors.

What is the problem?

```
# run the Excel app (application layer) on your computer using the COM object:
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

#change the Visible property of the COM object:
$objExcel.visible=$true

#open an Excel file (a workbook):
$myWorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strExcelFileLocal,$null,$true)
```

Where is the difference between clicking in Explorer and opening via PowerShell?

thank you
Chris

Comment: Can you try it without other arguments and jus the path itself? `$objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strExcelFileLocal)`

Comment: Is `$strExcelFileLocal` a full, **absolute** path and filename? Also, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open#remarks) the second parameter should be either `0` or `3`. I don't think `$null` would be ok. Usually, if you want to use the default value for a Variant parameter you should use `[Type]::Missing`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala same without arguments.

Comment: @Theo it is a full (local) path with full filename. i have tried with 0/3/ without arguments, nothing changes.

Comment: this error comes with every excel file that i open with PowerShell

Comment: Then perhaps [this](https://randomtecharticles.com/excel-name-conflict-with-_filterdatabase/) may help